# How to remove the images from aloha editor?

Tags: aloha-editor

I would like to remove the image handlers in the aloha-editor but i can't figure out how. 
I tried using settings.contenthandler.allows but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the default image plugin from the plugins list. But to remove handling for images,  removed the selection range from the document. 
document.selection.empty();